# How to pass an object from client to server Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How do I pass a large object from my client to my node.js server, the object is stored in a variable in my script tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run an ajax request and I would probably use JSON for it. This is an example using jQuery (the template engine is irrelevant, this is just JavaScript):

```
var data = {'bob':'foo','paul':'dog'};
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: 'POST',
   contentType:'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   dataType:'json'
 });
```

Comment: It's usually best to avoid giving an answer in jQuery unless they specifically mention using it.

Comment: Note that the `dataType` property indicates the expected response format, which may or may not be JSON in the OP's case (and is redundant if the response is ignored).

Comment: @adamz4008 Thankfully. =) I was a big proponent of jQuery back in the day, but now it's pretty much all vanilla JS now that the standards and browsers have caught up.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would any other client/server. Since clients and servers are detached, the server-side technology is irrelevant (though it does depend what type of endpoints).

Assuming you are using HTTP endpoints, you would simply use AJAX. You'd take your data, turn it into JSON, and then send it along.

With vanilla JavaScript on modern browsers, the easiest approach is with `fetch()`, which looks like this:

```
fetch('url-to-endpoint', {
  method: "POST",
  body: dataVariable
}).then(response => console.log(response.json()));
```

That's a basic POST. You can read up on all the ins and outs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) if you want to do something fancier.